# What does "HC" signify in a font name?

Tags: fonts, terminology, font-licensing

Examples: Arial HC, IDAutomationHC39M.
It seems to show up most strong textfrequently with free fonts.

Comment: [Related list of font-related abbreviations](http://help.fontshop.com/hc/en-us/articles/202693665-What-do-all-of-these-abbreviations-mean-), though it doesn't have HC

Comment: In general, acronyms in font titles merely indicate the foundry/vendor the font came from. International Type Company puts "ITC" on all their fonts, Font Font puts "FF", Letterhead Fonts puts "LHF" and so on.... I don't know what "HC" stands for, but my guess would be its the same sort of thing.

Comment: I found that list when I was searching for the answer for my coworker. It's such a comprehensive list that I'm surprised "HC" is not mentioned. I'd still like to find out what it is since it is being applied to a version of a typeface like Arial as well as a barcode font. It doesn't show up as part of any of my "professional-grade" fonts. Perhaps a limited and free version of a font? Google has not helped much.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this has a broad or general meaning at all (unless perhaps we are strictly talking about barcode fonts). I looked into the font you mentioned, IDAutomationHC39M and here's what I found.

- IDAutomation is [the company](http://www.idautomation.com/) that made this font.
- H stands for "human-readable"
- C39 is the [type of code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_39) the barcode is (Code 39)
- M [is the size](http://www.idautomation.com/barcode-fonts/code-39/fontnames.html) of the font (1 cm)

As confirmation for this, I did some extra digging and found this excerpt regarding their code 39 font:

> Contains 48 different Code 39 font versions for optimal compatibility
>   with normal, human-readable, extended and symbol versions.

([Source](http://www.idautomation.com/barcode-fonts/code-39/))

**EDIT**

And to address Arial HC, [just about every](http://fontsup.com/full-search/hc-fonts.html) other font with HC I find is an outline font